# Fitting Hill function to a given dataset

Tags: fitting

I have the following data:

```
data = {{15, 1}, {18, 1470.7`/1476.9333333333334`}, {21, 1326.2333333333333`/1476.9333333333334`}, {24, 316.8`/1476.9333333333334`}};
```

Based on the data and knowledge of the underlying dynamics, Hill function, i.e., $f (x) = a^n / (a^n + x^n)$, can be a good candidate for fitting; and, $a$ and $n$ to be determined from the data. So, we have:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a^n/(a^n + x^n), {a, n}, x]
```

which gives error:

```
The function value {-1475.9327805109833`+0.0002583292146366989`I,-1469.699783452097`+0.0001011495715564914`I,-1325.2332352782923`+0.00004579492074835434` I,-44.140176596973895`+0.00002305423442489074` I} is not a list of \real numbers withdimensions {4} at {a,n} = {-3.5525189040549865`,-5.13906385562555`}.
```

How can this be fixed?

**EDIT**

Now, by adding the constraint $a > 0$ and $n > 0$, the error is fixed and Mathematica returns an answer:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {a^n/(a^n + x^n), a > 0, n > 0}, {a, n}, x]

***2.17245*10^17/(2.17245*10^17 + x^6.18796)***
```

But, it doesn't seem it fits the data:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 15, 24}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: You can add constraints on the parameters, and/or provide an initial value for them. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: You can add constraints wo your model as in `{a^n/(a^n + x^n), a > 0, n > 0}`; please have a look at the documentation.

Comment: @BobHanlon 's answer (+1) is a good example of the advantage of having good starting values.  But I would argue that by dividing by the largest response variable the model actually being fit is `c a^n/(a^n + x^n)` so there are 3 parameters with just 4 data points.  That suggests overfitting and fudging to me.  Some tempering of the feeling of a good fit can be achieved by using the `SinglePredictionBands` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include estimates of parameters in [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{15, 1}, {18, 1470.7`/1476.9333333333334`}, {21, 
     1326.2333333333333`/1476.9333333333334`}, {24, 
     316.8`/1476.9333333333334`}} // Rationalize;

f[a_, n_, x_] := a^n/(a^n + x^n)
```

Develop estimates for parameters

```
eqns = (f[a, n, #[[1]]] - #[[2]] == 0 & /@ data[[{1, -1}]])

(* {-1 + a^n/(15^n + a^n) == 0, -(216/1007) + a^n/(24^n + a^n) == 0} *)

est = NArgMin[{Total[eqns[[All, 1]]^2], a > 0, n > 0}, {a, n}]

(* {22.8901, 27.4141} *)

(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[a, n, x],
    Transpose[{{a, n}, est}], x])["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 22.8313, n -> 25.9977} *)

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {15, 24} *)

Plot[nlm[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why the fit is as good as it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an extended comment.  In short, that model can't provide a reasonable fit to your data.

The model can be rewritten as the following:

$$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n+1}$$

Given that all of the responses are greater than 1 (and real), that means that

$\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n+1<1$ or $\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n<0$.  That can only potentially happen if $a<0$ and $n$ is an odd integer.

There does not appear to be a combination of $a$ and $n$ satisfying those restrictions that can match more than a single data point.

Comment: Your adjustment essentially is adding an additional parameter and with 3 parameters and just 4 data points, that doesn't lend to having much confidence in the fit.  (And I do really understand that maybe even those 4 data points were very expensive to obtain.)

Comment: That is a very interesting problem but my advice is to get more data.  You have 4 parameters (actually at least 5 counting the error structure which has currently been ignored) and only 8 data points.  (Biological systems as opposed to Physics systems require many more data points than one would like.  And I do understand that getting more data is many times impossible.)